# fb:login-button click from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, facebook

```
<fb:login-button id="fblogin" onlogin="location.href='/Custom/SocialMediaAuth/Auth.aspx?facebookauth=false'" scope="">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Hi,

I understand that you cannot manipulate the above code.

But I would like to click it from `jQuery`

the Code `$('#fblogin').click();` is not working.

Is there anyway to click it? I do not wish to use the javascript functions to log in.

If there's no way to do it, how can i make the page to pop up the facebook log in box and redirect to the url mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know it is not allowed and not possible,

**Alternatively you can do this :-**

Make your javascript function

```
function fblogin(url_to_redirect) {
  FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
        top.location.href = url_to_redirect;
     }
     else {
     }
 }, {scope:'email,manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream'});
}
```

Create a button

```
<input type="button" id="fblogin">
```

On button's click event you can call this function.

```
$('#fblogin').click(function(){
   fblogin(url_to_redirect)
});
```

Comment: yup. that's wht I want. Thanks.